# How do I pull a variable from Arduino Ethernet-Shield using PHP (WAMP server)?

Tags: arduino, ethernet

How can I pull a variable located in Arduino RAM through an Ethernet Shield from my PHP ([WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP)) server?

For example, I have a variable, `red_led = 1`,  in the Arduino. How can I pull that information to my PHP server?

Comment: This is very similar to your previous question. Are you asking about the general approach or the specifics? If it's the specifics, be more specific. What code have you tried, what problems have you encountered? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19854/how-do-i-program-arduino-uno-ethernet-with-php-using-wampserver

Comment: We are not the arduino help desk.

Comment: As much as we will try to help out, Arduino questions are best handled by the [Arduino.SE](http://arduino.stackexchange.com) or the Arduino forums.  Areas made specifically for Arduino questions.  EE.SE is more for physical electronics design rather than Arduino web servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a public IP address in your Arduino device, you can repeatedly make requests from your WAMP server. But the Arduino has to listen on some port and respond to your request.

The better solution is, every time the variable changes its state, the Arduino connects to your WAMP server and sends the desired data. For example, it makes an HTTP GET request:

```
http://example.com/variable-from-arduino.php?red_led=1
```

And that's it. Every time, when the Arduino sends a GET request, you can process it on your server.

If you just want to print some graphs based on your variable, you can use [Pachube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosm_%28Internet_of_Things%29).

Comment: Thanks yes the GET method works, but what about POST method? example http://192.168.1.35/test.php/?red_status=5  <<< this works only with GET method. but now i want to send in POST method.

Comment: Well, GET method is more easy than POST. GET contains only HTTP header, it has no body. But if you want to use POST instead, look here — http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod There is example, how POST request looks.

Comment: With POST, your data is stored in an environment variable.  You will need to retrieve the "CONTENT-LENGTH" environment variable and then use that to read in the length of the contents of the environment variable your data is stored in.  I don't think this would be different on the Arduino platform.